# Can't access self variable inside query function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
//This is a Route  
function doSomething(){  
var self=this;   
var a,b,c;   
//do something  
reqArray="somevalue";   
this.store.query("record",{"filter":"[{'api_name':'somevalue','comparator':'somevalue','value':"+reqArray+"}]"})
  .then(function(data){                       
    //can't access a,b,c or self              
  });  
}
```

I get the data i need inside the then function after the promise is resolved but i am not able to access anything outside the then function.
Editing for more clarification: this variable inside then function is window.i want to be able to reference the route .

Comment: You can access it there. There will not be any issues.

Comment: `this` is `window` there

Comment: so how will i access self in doSomething inside then?

Comment: Use bind on the function : `then((function(data){ ... }).bind(self))` to have self var as `this` in the function

Comment: Can you provide a non-working twiddle?

Comment: What is it that makes you think you cannot access?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really need all your vars in your object, you can do something like this :

```
function doSomething(){  
    var self=this;   
    var a,b,c;
    //do something
    // Save value
    self.a = a;
    self.b = b;
    self.c = c;
    reqArray="somevalue";   
    this.store.query("record",{"filter":"[{'api_name':'somevalue','comparator':'somevalue','value':"+reqArray+"}]"}).then(
        (function(data){                     
            // this = self
            // this.a = a
            // ...            
        }).bind(self));  
}
```

Comment: Why would this be necessary?

Comment: I didn't say this is necessary. It's just a way to do it, particularly if you want to change `this` in the function

Answer (score -1):

you're using Ember right?

why cant you make use of the arrow function which will preserve the context of this:

```
.then((data)=> {...})
```

Comment: But being able to access `a` etc. should have nothing to do with `this`.

Comment: But clearly it has everything to do with `this`?!

In the original post it was claimed `this` was a reference to `window` - why is this? Its because the anonymous closure function within the `then` changed the value of `this` to `window` hence why `this.a` wouldnt exist. (`window.a` would be undefined) By using the 'fat' arrow function `this` will be preserved and you will be able to use `this.a` within. This is exactly what '.bind(self)` is doing - its binding the context of `this` into the closure function. Anyway both would work... unless I'm missing something??